Firemonkey - differentiate left from right Ctrl & Shift keys
When capturing keys on the OnKeyDown event, I get those values for Ctrl & Shift keys:
. for left and right Ctrl  Key parameter = 17
. for left and right Shift key parameter = 16
How can I check if the key is the left Ctrl or the right Ctrl (same for Shift)?
Any help will be appreciated.
